# Unable to login to cloudbyte elastistor, incorrect login

Tags: installation, operating-system

I am trying the host name as user name and password as entered during installation. The login screen in CLI keeps on giving incorrect login error. How to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default username for elastistor is **root**.
Use the password as configured during installation.